# iphonesdk using tableview and html

Tags: iphone

im making an application where i have to load my database from html file which is in my resource folder. i have a table view and when i click on a certain cell it will open html file based on that click. can any one help me how to do this. thanks

Comment: What exactly part of what you described you can't do? What have you already done yourself?

Comment: i done till tableview. now i have to use html in the webview. how can i load an html file in my webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// create a web view in "cellForRowAtIndexPath"

```
UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
[wv loadHTMLString: << your html >> baseURL: nil];
wv.delegate = self;
```

// implement the webView delegate

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [self.view addSubView:webView];  // or push onto the naviation controller
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think when you 'didSelectCellAtIndex' in the table view will open a new view controller with the webview. And you have also mapping of each cell with the corresponding html file name. Then in the viewDidLoad method of your next VC, you can use this code, while webView is the outlet pointing to your UIWebView. And htmlFileName is the html file's name.

```
  [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
          [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
          pathForResource:htmlFileName 
          ofType:@"html"] 
          isDirectory:NO] ] ];
```